# Determine the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need to calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$ .
It seems very "similar" to Taylor expansion of functions arcsin(x) and its derivative for x = -2.

It is known: $arcsin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{(2n-1)!!x^{2n+1}}}{2^{n}n!(2n+1)}$.

When derivative applied we get: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(2n+1)(2n-1)!!x^{2n}}}{2^{n}n!(2n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(2n-1)!!x^{2n}}}{2^{n}n!}$.

What to do next? Am I on the wrong trace here?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: $\frac{cos(2)}{2}$

Comment: It's even more "similar" to,

$$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
 
Divide it by $2$ and substitute $x=2$ to get your result (as shown by d.k.o)

Answer (score 2):

It surprises me to see that you are familiar with the rather obscure series of $\arcsin x$, and yet, at the same time, fail to recognize one of the most well-known series in math, namely that of $\cos x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}~.~$ Also, $\sin x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}~.$ Remember that $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~,~$ and then recall [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm interested in the definitions of "linear" knowledge and "thinking too linearly."  Perhaps the OP has seen the TS for the cosine function and just for a moment, didn't recognize it herein.

Comment: @Zach466920 I didn't ask for "definitions for the words," I stated that I'm interested in your definitions of phrases (e.g., "linear knowledge").  What is "linear knowledge?"  And a "moment" is not limited to an hour+, so my conjecture is viable.  My comment is not intended to provoke debate or create unhealthy tension.  Rather, I hope each of us can be more empathetic towards problems others have in appealing for help.  While your math skills are better than some, they are dwarfed by best-in-class mathematicians.  Would you enjoy having them publicly criticize you?  Humility is a key here.

Comment: @Zach466920 No worry.  And I do understand the sentient better now.  Best wishes and "happy mathing!"